# Cannot resolve symbol "android:title"

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I have this warn on my ActionBar how can i fix it?
"Cannot resolve symbol @string/info" on android:title

XML menu:

```
<!-- "Mark Favorite", should appear as action button if possible -->
<item
    android:id="@+id/howto"
    android:icon="@drawable/info"
    android:title="@string/info"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
<!-- Settings, should always be in the overflow -->
```

Activity:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Add a string resource named `info`, presumably.

Comment: You have defined it into strings.xml, right?

Comment: Yes, i do it @anfuca

Answer (score 0):

You can try it as:

```
<item
      name="@string/info"
      id="@+id/howto"
      icon="@drawable/info"
      app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
```

Hope this help!